# Is bit stuffing done after 6 or 5 consecutive 1's?

Tags: computer-architecture, bus

I am learning computer architecture and organization. I have the following doubt.

I have read that in bit stuffing a 0 is inserted whenever 6 consecutive 1’s are encountered. However, it may be noted that in some other bit stuffing systems, a 0 is inserted after five consecutive 1’s are encountered.

So if a question comes like - If we apply bit stuffing on the bit stream 100011111110011111101, the
output bit stream will be:" Should I do bit stuffing after 6 or 5 consecutive 1's?

Can someone please help me?

Reference:
[Week 10: Assignment Solutions](https://nptel.ac.in/content/storage2/courses/106105163/ASSIGNMENT-SOLUTION-WEEK10.pdf) question number 8

Comment: What's the context? I am curious why "6 consecutive 1s". There is no such generic definition for bit stuffing I could find.

Comment: It depends on what standard you're going by.

Comment: Some systems may even stuff after three or four consecutive 1s. It's all a trade off between bandwidth and synchronization needs.

Comment: SDLC used bit stuffing (insert a logical 1) after 6 consecutive logical 1s for everything within a data frame as the framing symbol is 01111110.  Bits are added to prevent a framing symbol being inadvertently added within the frame.

Comment: @PeterSmith Perhaps you did not understood my question my question is - if a question comes like - If we apply bit stuffing on the bit stream 100011111110011111101, the output bit stream will be:" Should I do bit stuffing after 6 or 5 consecutive 1's?

Comment: @ANSHULGUPTA ... you did not "read and understand" question 8 ... you are going off on a tangent that is not necessary

Comment: **it may be noted that in some other bit stuffing systems**.  Your instructor is indicating that there are other approaches, but they want 6!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bit stuffing is done according to the standard at hand.

In this case, you are asked to do bit stuffing where the bit-stuffing rule is not given, but it is in the context of a multiple-choice question.  So the problem becomes not one of engineering, but in second-guessing the teacher.

In an ideal world, you ask the instructor to clarify the question.  That doesn't always work.  If you can't do that, then -- you second-guess the teacher.

From the context of the question *and the possible answers* it appears that bit-stuffing is supposed to happen after six consecutive ones -- there's no answer to choose from where bit-stuffing happens after five consecutive ones.  So, run with that.

As noted, in an actual practical project, you're either given a standard that specifies when and how bit-stuffing is to be performed.  In a few cases you're *designing* a standard and *you* specify (or more likely a committee that you're on, after much argument, specifies) when and how bit-stuffing is to be performed.

Comment: "there's no example given where bit-stuffing happens after five consecutive ones", I think you mean "there's no option given where bit-stuffing happens after five consecutive ones". Am I right?

Comment: Edited!  I don't know if it's *better*, but it's *different* now!